# (Python) Creating a 2d list (map) from a file

Tags: python, list, 2d

So I'm trying to get my program to read the elements of a text file then create a 2d list that is 20x30 with the elements of the text file. My expected outcome of this is essentially a game map in which I can find certain elements and move them as need be.

The two functions i have so far for trying to do this are as follows, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want it to do, and I'm kind of stumped as to why I can't.

```
def create_level(level):
     """ Create the level based off of reading positions of agents, player, buildings
water, etc..."""

     a_maze = []

     level_data = level.read()
     for r in range (0, ROWS, 1):
        a_maze.append ([])
        for c in range (0, COLUMNS, 1):
             a_maze[r].append (level_data)
     print(a_maze)



def load_level():
     while True:
          print("Enter the name/directory of the level file you wish to load\
     .txt or .lvl are the only accepted formats")

          level_in = input(">>: ")
          if (level_in.endswith(".txt") or level_in.endswith(".lvl")):
               try:
                    level = open(level_in, "r")

               except IOError:
                    print("Not a valid file")
          else:
               print("Not a suitable format for level")

          return level
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing here is the parsing of the file. All `open` does in python is create a file object (in this case, a text file object), which you can read or write to. Assuming each tile in the map is a separate character, and each line is the full width of the map, here's how you could construct the map line-by-line:

```
your_map = []
with open(level_in, 'r') as level:
    for line in level:
        your_map.append([a for a in line.split()])
```

Edit: If your map file has no delimiters at all between tiles, just change the append line to:

```
your_map.append(list(line))
```

Padraic Cunningham also suggests that the `your_map` assignment could be further condensed like so, with delimiters:

```
your_map = [line.split(your_delimiters) for line in level]
```

or like so, without delimiters:

```
your_map = [list(line) for line in level]
```

Both of these would completely remove the need for a `for` loop.

A few notes:

The `with` keyword is used to automatically destruct objects like file objects when you're done with them - this is a whole lot easier and safer than having to remember to call level.close() after you're done.

The `for line in level` iterates through the file object on a line-by-line basis, which will automatically end when the end of file is reached.

The `[a for a in line.split]` is a list comprehension, but what it boils down to in this case is that you're creating a new list where every index is one of the non-space tokens in your line string.

This code I wrote above makes a couple assumptions - firstly, that your text file has the same number of tiles in each line, and secondly that each tile is delimited from the previous tile by a space. Here's an example of what I'm imagining:

```
` ` ` o # ` . . .
` ` o # # # . . .
` o # # # # # . .
```

where any given character corresponds to say, desert, water, etc.

Comment: don't use map as a variable name

Comment: you could use itertools.chain to create the array then line lengths won't matter

Comment: I like this idea, it seems a lot more python(y). The while loop was there to ensure that input of the correct form is received. Lastly I'll look into it again, but the character in each map is not separated by a space, as a space just denotes an empty space of which the player is free to move to.

Just like to add, love the community here, I asked a question and you answered in what, 2 minutes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How do you mean? I'm presuming he's creating the map files with the intention that any given line corresponds to a full map span. I may have misunderstood you, though.

Comment: @NathanGeist Do you have any delimiters at all? I'll add an example for that case.

Comment: nvm won't work, on another note `list(line)  == [a for a in line]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, I know there was a better way I was forgetting. Googled for it but couldn't come up with anything quickly. Thanks!

Comment: no worries, last suggestion! `your_map = [list(line.rstrip()) for line in level]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Beautiful!

Comment: Thanks all, awesome that I can get an answer and back to work on it within the same hour.